# QUnit & sinon. Spying on a function called asynchronously

Tags: backbone.js, asynchronous, qunit, sinon

With Sinon, I'm trying to spy on an async function call from a function in my qunit test:

```
test("requestLiveCategoriesData should call parseCategoriesData", function(){
        var spy = sinon.spy(this.liveCategoriesModel, 'parseCategoriesData');
        this.liveCategoriesModel.requestLiveCategoriesData();
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
    });
```

The test fails (`expected parseCategoriesData to be called once but was called 0 times`) even though parseCategoriesData does indeed get called by the requestLiveCategoriesData - I know this because `parseCategoriesData called` is output to the console when I run the test in the browser

This is the code I'm testing (simplified for the sake of the question):

```
requestLiveCategoriesData: function () {
    console.log('getting live categories');
    try {
        console.log("--- RETRIEVING LIVE CATEGORIES EVENTS ---");

        liveCategoriesCall = new LiveEventRequest(eventObjRequest);
        liveCategoriesCall.on('reset', this.parseCategoriesData, this); //the spied on function is called from here
        liveCategoriesCall.fetch({ 
            success: function (collection, resp, options) { 
                console.log('Live Categories Events Request complete.');
            },
            error: function(collection, resp) {
                console.log("Error on Live Categories Events Request");
                if (_.has(resp, 'statusText') && resp.statusText === "timeout") {
                    /* Timeout error handling */
                    console.log("Live Categories Events Request Timeout");
                }
                Conf.generalNetworkError();
            },
            complete: function (resp, textStatus) {
                console.log("Live Categories Request teardown.");
                if (liveCategoriesCall) { liveCategoriesCall.off('reset', that.parseCategoriesData, that); }
            },
            cache:false,
            timeout: that.get('liveEventsTimeout')
        });

    } catch(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: PROCESSING LIVE CATEGORIES");
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log(err.stack);
        if (liveCategoriesCall) { liveCategoriesCall.off('reset', this.parseEventsData, this); }
        this.set({ 
            'lastRequest': (new Date()).getTime(),
            'liveCategories': []
        });
        this.trigger("errorAPI", err.message);
    }
},    


parseCategoriesData: function (liveCategoriesCall) {
    console.log('parseCategoriesData called');
},
```

Am I going about this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You at least need to instruct QUnit to wait on the asynchronous response call using [async()](https://api.qunitjs.com/async/).

Now when you've got that set up you need to figure out when you can call `sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);`. It looks like there is currently no way to know when the `LiveEventRequest` has returned data.

If you have no way of modifying the current code using a setTimeout to wait a bit is your only (bad) option.

If you can change your code you should probably investigate if you can return a promise from the `requestLiveCategoriesData` call. Have the promise resolve when the data has arrived. Then you can wait on that promise before you do the Sinon check and follow that by a done() call like in the QUnit async documentation.

And while we're at it: You probably should use a sinon fakeserver or some other way to mock the results of the `LiveEventRequest` as well.